# Integrate Karate results into a database for test automation

Tags: sql, json, database, cucumber, karate

Has anyone that has used Karate Framework and worked with the JSON / HTML reporting, integrated them with a database? If so would love to hear your thoughts and how that works?

I know Karate produces Cucumber JSON outputs and I was looking for plugins or some suggestions to integrate with a respective (SQL or noSQL database, still need to choose this)

Thanks!